# `$PATH` at end or beginning of `PATH` export in .bash_profile (for Git on Mac)

Tags: macos, git, path, bash

I'm finding a lot of suggestions online for one of two basic ways to specify the `PATH` export in ~/.bashprofile for Git on Mac, but I haven't found an explanation for which of the two is preferable and why.

Could anyone describe the difference between these two placements of the `$PATH`? Thanks!

`export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing my search terms, I found this technical piece outlining the difference: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm

It seems placing the `$PATH` at the *end* of the statement (`export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH`) assures that the system looks in this custom place *before* searching default places (that is, the specified path is appended *before* the standard places contained within `$PATH`).

Placing the `$PATH` variable at the *beginning* of the statement (`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin`) doesn't work in cases where a default path already exists, because the system looks in the default places (given in `PATH`) *before* getting to the statement's custom-specified path.

Comment: Correct. Paths are evaluated in the order given. One should also be weary that listing too many uncommon special-case paths before commonly used ones like /bin and /usr/bin could have a performance impact (especially if network file systems are involved). I only prepend paths if I really need to override existing commands, which is quite uncommon.